# What data type is used to store Uint8List data for an image in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I trying to upload an image in to my PostgreSQL database.

First I got the image from a computer at runtime as a `Uint8List`.

I want to know :

1. what data type should I set the field (lets say field `imagedata`) in the PostgreSQL database for it to accept and store a `Uint8List` data from my web app?
2. Can I create the table to accept the image as follows:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE imagetable(
       id serial primary key not null,
       imagedata [datatype?],
   );
   ```
3. Can I also enter the data as follows:

   ```
   INSERT into imagetable(imagedata)
   values (imagedataWebApp)
   ```

   where `imagedataWebApp` is the `Uint8List` data from my web app.

Comment: If `imagedata` means e.g. a JPG or PNG, then the column should be defined as `bytea`

Comment: But will it accept Uint8List data types which looks like: [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0,....,220, 55, 109, 231, 63, 255, 217]?

Comment: That looks more like an array of integers rather than an "image". In that case `bigint[]` (an array of bigints) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: What is an `Uint8List`, which programming language are you using? If it's anything like JavaScript's `Uint8Array`, that's really a byte array, which should be a `bytea`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Looks like an array of bytes (octets) though, not of bigints, given the range 0…255.

Comment: I am writing in dart for a flutter web app

Comment: the Uint8List data type is  Byte data for a file. Particularly useful if you want to manipulate its data or easily upload to somewhere else. (according to flutter docs). I think @Bergi is right it is an array of bytes!